# Got stuck in a L'hopital's rule loop while solving the limit of $x^{x^{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Basically, I was solving this limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{x^{x}}$$

And this is my solution:

$L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{x^{x}}\\
x = e^{lnx}\\
\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{(lnx)^{x^{x}}}\\
L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{x^{x}(\ln x)}\\
\ln L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln e^{x^{x}(\ln x)}\\
\ln L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} {x^{x}(\ln x)}\ln e\\
\ln L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} {x^{x}(\ln x)}\\
\ln L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} {e^{x\ln x}(\ln x)}$

Is my process right? Am I arriving at the right answer? When I use the L'hopital's rule at this state it just starts to loop.

Any help would be appreciated :D Thanks!

Comment: This will be easier to read if you use `\ln`

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake :) I fixed it and hope that there won't be another mistake

Comment: @Dumbone  No problem :)

Comment: How did you use L'hôpital's rule?  On a form $0/0$; on a form $\infty/\infty$; on something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to use L’Hôpital’s rule. You correctly got $$\ln L = \lim_{x\to0^+} x^x \ln x $$

$x^x$ has a limit at $0$, as $$x^x = e^{x\ln x} \to e^0 =1 $$ while $\ln x \to -\infty$ Therfore, $$\ln L = 1\times -\infty =-\infty $$ and so $$L=0$$